# Can I cross compile GO binary for ARMv7 on OS X?

Tags: go, cross-compiling

I have a GO program and I want to give its binary to a customer for running on RaspberryPi 3. I am cross compiling the GO program on OS X by setting `GOARM=7` and `GOOS=linux` in the environment as per the instructions at https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GoArm. However, the binary could not be run on RPi3. It fails with this error.

```
cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I am pretty sure there might be issue in cross-compilation but it's clear what is the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you specify the `GOARCH=arm` environment variable ? What is the output of `file <binary name>` ? `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped` is the output I get from file for `export GOARCH=arm; GOARM=7; GOOS=linux go build ls.go`.

Comment: @ChristianWitts `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped`. I figured that I will have to set `GOARCH=arm` after asking this question. Giving it a try now but seems like that might be the issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you did and what versions of used software are involved? There are no RPi3 instructions behind the given link, as far as I can tell. Also, did you check the bug tracker?